# Can this query, which groups users by amount of comments posted, be simplified?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

Two tables are used in this query, and all that matters in the result is the number of users which have or haven't posted any comments so far. The table `user` of course has the column `id`, which is the foreign key in the table `comment`, identified by the column `user_id`.

The first super-simple query groups users by whether or not they have any comments so far. It outputs two rows (a row with the user count who have comments, and a row with the user count who have no comments), with two columns (number of users, and whether or not they have posted any comments).

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(id) AS user_count, 
    IF( id IN ( SELECT user_id FROM `comment` ), 1, 0) AS has_comment
FROM `user`
GROUP BY has_comment
```

An example of how the output would look like here:

```
+------------+-------------+
| user_count | has_comment |
+------------+-------------+
| 150        | 0           |
| 140        | 1           |
+------------+-------------+
```

Now here comes my question. I want slightly more information here, by grouping these users into 3 groups instead:

1. Users that have posted no comments
2. Users that have posted fewer than 10 comments
3. Users that have posted 10 or more comments

And the best query that I know how to write for this purpose is as follows, which works, but unfortunately runs 4 subqueries and has 2 derived tables:

```sql
SELECT 
   COUNT(id) AS user_count,
   CASE
      WHEN id IN ( SELECT user_id FROM ( SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS comment_count, user_id FROM `comment` GROUP BY user_id HAVING comment_count >= 10 ) AS a) THEN '10 or more'
      WHEN id IN ( SELECT user_id FROM ( SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS comment_count, user_id FROM `comment` GROUP BY user_id HAVING comment_count < 10 ) AS b) THEN 'less than 10'
      ELSE 'none'
   END AS has_comment
FROM `user`
GROUP BY has_comment
```

An example of the output here would be something like:

```
+------------+-------------+
| user_count | has_comment |
+------------+-------------+
| 150        | none        |
| 130        | less than 10|
| 100        | 10 or more  |
+------------+-------------+
```

This second query; can it be written more simply and efficiently, and still produce the same kind of result? (potentially maybe even be expanded into more of these kinds of "groups")

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  and add the source data for your results.

Comment: Thank you, i will take that into account for future notice; this time it seems i've already gotten an answer regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select
    count(*) no_users,
    case
        when no_comments = 0 then 'none'
        when no_comments < 10 then 'less than 10'
        else '10 or more'
    end has_comment
from (
    select 
        u.id, 
        (select count(*) from comments c where c.user_id = u.id) no_comments
    from users u
) t
group by has_comment
order by no_comments
```

The subquery counts how many comments each user has (you could also express this with a `left join` and aggregation); then, the outer query classifies and count the users per number of comments.